# Json query to Elasticsearch aggregation query using ejs

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to convert below Json query in form of ejs aggregation can anyone help me it would be appreciated.

```
 {
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "quantity": {
                    "gte": "500"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I converted it like below but it is not working getting exception "Argument must be a Query"

```
ejs.Request().query(ejs.FilterAggregation('filtered').filter(ejs.RangeFilter('quantity').gt(200)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ejs.Request().query(ejs.FilteredQuery(ejs.MatchAllQuery(), ejs.RangeFilter('quantity').gte(500)))
```